# How to create an event in magento 2 mailchimp programmatically?

Tags: magento2, php, mailchimp

Basically I have successfully connected mailchimp with magento 2 and I am able to see my magento store data in mailchimp backend. Also I can see mailchimp in magento 2 backend and I have pulled the code using the command below. But my question is how should I create an event programmatically by making api call to mailchimp as per their guide?. I am referring to https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/create-custom-events/ also I tried to find any another resource which can help me implement the coding part of creating an event but I didn't find any relevant resources. It would be great if I can get any suggestions or advice from where to start? because it would really help me to learn mailchimp using magento 2.

```
composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an event for product retargeting.
Mailchimp already have an automation for this

[image: take a look]